# Batchfile with user acess authorization, and verson checker

Tags: batch-file

Here is my situation

I have a batchfile script, runs from a USB memory. (installing stuff)

I want 4 users to have rights to run it. But I don't want the script to be used by others. (self destructive or something)

Can this be done from a batchfile:
*Example*
I have a txt stored at mydomain.com/iplist.txt Containing global IP for users
I have a txt stored at mydomain.com/version.txt containing the newest version number.

Then when user runs script it check his global IP and check if mydomain.com/iplist.txt contains his IP.
If correct continue to versioncheck
If failed exit or "self destruct" or something.

Im not asking for a code. Is it possible? :-)

Comment: Can you please go through your post and fix your spelling mistakes?  I could do it myself but figure its best to give you a chance to fix it yourself first.

Comment: Hope this is more correct. Done a spell checker :-)

Comment: A batch file can do anything that external programs permit.  A batch file does provide support for an "IF" command, and a "GOTO" command.  One semi-easy thing to do is to check "%USERNAME%", e.g.: IF "%USERNAME"="OKUserName" echo OK (or instead of "echo OK", use "GOTO okuser" and place ":okuser" in the batch file).  Will that work okay, or does it need to be checked by IP address?  If so, that's the specific piece that must be checked...  I suspect solutions might include using WMIC and FIND.  Adding as a comment, not an answer, since this info is just a partial solution.

Comment: The reason i think IP is the solution is because. the program will be used one many computers. But I will close it to 4 electronic stores. I have thougt about password but its to easy to "give away"